# Redirect Regex for URLs

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, redirect

I have a Wordpress site and I'd like to redirect traffic based on specific criteria. I'm using a redirect plugin that has a Source URL (which can be a regex) and a Destination URL that can contain the result from the regex such as $1.

`/blog/{slug}` should redirect to `/{slug}` but only when `{slug}` is not `?page=` or `page/{anything}`

So `/blog/the-article-name` will redirect to `/the-article-name` but `/blog/?page=3` will not redirect and `/blog/page/3` will not redirect.

Also, `/blog/category/{slug}` should redirect to `/{slug}`.

Thanks

Comment: are you using nginx or apache or what?

Comment: I'm actually using a redirect plugin that allows for a regex in one field and then the result in another field. For example: the source URL is `event/category/(.*)` and the destination is `/event/$1`

Comment: or, what's the environment then? PHP?

Comment: It's PHP, but this is a Wordpress site with a redirection plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out after some trial and error:

`^/blog\/(?!.*(page\/.*|\?paged=))+(.+)`

I can access the 2nd match (the slug) using `/$2`

`https://example.com/blog/the-article-slug` will match for group 2 and redirect to `https://example.com/the-article-slug`

`https://example.com/blog/page/2` will not match for group 2
`https://example.com/blog/?paged=2` will not match for group 2

I'm using another redirect rule, `^/blog/category/(.*)` to match the slug which I can access using `/$1`

`https://example.com/blog/category/the-article-slug` will match for group 1 and redirect to `https://example.com/the-article-slug`

Hope this helps someone else